# Number of Words in a file, c++

Tags: c++, file, count, stream

I am trying to count the number of words in a file, I know this question has been asked but I have tried some implementations I have seen but I keep getting an error.

The line in the file I am reading is "Super Chill" but when I run the code I get a count 3, where >> gets Super the first time and then Chill twice. I have a couple questions regarding this method:

1) what does While(in) look for? How does it know when to stop?

2) Why is "Chill" getting stored twice with >>?

Here is the code

```
int countWords(std::istream& in){ // line in file is -> Super Chill

    int count = 0;
    std::string word;
    while (in) {
        in >> word;
        if (word != "") {
            count+= 1;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: change it to `while(in >> word) { ++count; }`

Comment: Works but do you mind answering what While(in) was doing exactly and why I was getting "chill" twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`while (in)` checks if no error has occurred. It's the same as writing `while (!in.fail())`

After you call `in >> word` and get the first "Chill", `while (in)` still is true, until the next call to `in >> word`. When you hit `in >> word` again it fails because it's at the end of the file and doesn't write anything to `word`, but the `word` variable still has "Chill" in it from the last time, so you count it a second time. Then the `while (in)` finally fails on the next iteration.

Calling `while (in >> word) { ++count; }` works because `in >> word` is actually the function `in.operator>>(word)` which happens to return an `istream&`, and an `istream` has an `operator bool` method which allows you to use it in a condition instead of writing `!in.fail()`. Sort of roundabout, I know. Point is, it calls `in >> word`, *then* checks `if (in)` and if it passes *then* calls `++count;` and iterates again. Versus your original technique which counted the previous `word` even if `in >> word` failed.

To make this clearer, it might help to know that changing your original code's `if` statement to `if (in)` would have also worked, but would be sort of bad code.

As a final conclusion, the entire function could be written as:

```
int countWords(std::istream& in) {
    int count = 0;
    for (std::string word; in >> word; ++count) {}
    return count;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly does >> do? I know it grabs a word but does it move some reference along the line, what constitutes a "failure" in my original solution where >> didn't work the third time and while(in) failed?

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already gotten one solution to the problem you posted. You might want to consider another possibility though:

```
int countWords(std::istream& in){  
    return std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                         std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}
```

This doesn't actually *eliminate* the loop, but it hides it inside of `std::distance` where it's pretty difficult to mess things up.

Comment: I don't know much about istream_iterators or distance so this is confusing to me but I will definitely look it up, thanks i appreciate it!

Comment: @user2076774: Well worth learning about both (and the other iterators and algorithms).